# FluentValidation Doesn't work with different libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation, clean-architecture

So, I want to build, a simple project with clean architecture that uses FluentValidation. In My Domain layer(which has its own library) I have Teacher class and a TeacherAnnotation class as shown in the following:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
    public class TeacherAnnotation : AbstractValidator<Teacher>
{
    public TeacherAnnotation()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().MinimumLength(3).MaximumLength(50);
        RuleFor(x => x.Lastname).NotEmpty().MinimumLength(3).MaximumLength(50);
    }
}
```

In the presentation layer (which is a differeny library), in my Main Api, In startup I added the following:

```
services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation();
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Teacher>, TeacherAnnotation>();
```

And in my Data Layer (which is a different library), I run my migration (I keep my database logic and migrations there).
The Problem is that when I add-migration "initial" and update-database, every thing runs fine, however the FluentAnnotation does not work, I can just add Teachers in table without name or lastname and it does not restrict it, from the Api I can also add teachers with 2 char name or with just no name and it adds them in the database.
So in a word, what am I doing wrong?
P.S in the domain layer library I added NugetPackage of FluentValidation, and in Presentation Layer Api I added NugetPackage of FluentValidation and FluentValidation.aspnetcore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FluentValidation is used for data validation, but it is different from Fluent api. Its configuration will not generate constraints for ef core.

About these constraints, you can use this fluent api.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>()
            .HasCheckConstraint("CK_Teacher_Name", "datalength([Name])>6 And datalength([Name])<100")
            .Property("Name")
            .IsRequired();

    }
```

Note: Length of one character is 2 in datalength.

Comment: I Don't Really understand, I just need to use alternative for Data Annotations [required] [key] and so on, for this i want to use fluent validation to separate my files, however when I put my information in Different libraries it does not work. So you are saying that if i use different libraries i should write my code like you showed, and remove all of my fluent annotation code?

Comment: @givexa, FluentValidation does not involve ef core constraints, you need to use fluent api or annotation to generate the constraints.

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot it worked, so to sum up Fluent Api is used to check in database (in sql), if something is not right it will not add in the database, but what does fluentvalidation do? it is used in frontend or what?

Comment: You are welcome, this is an official explanation about fluentvalidation: 'A small validation library for .NET that uses a fluent interface and lambda expressions for building validation rules'. It is similar to model validation.